# IndexError: list index out of range even though I do not reference a value greater than the length of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, indexing

I have the following code that I have to run.

```
Solar = ['Solar',['C','2.6915D-04'],['H','1.0000D+00'],['K','1.0715D-07'],['N','6.7608D-05'],['O','4.8978D-04'],['Ar','2.5119D-06'],['Cl','3.1623D-07'],['Fe','3.1623D-05'],['He','8.5114D-02'],['Mg','3.9811D-05'],['Na','1.7378D-06'],['Si','3.2359D-05'],['Ti','8.9125D-08']]

front = 'cond_initial'

fSolar = open(front+'_'+Solar[0]+'.dat','w')



fin = open(front+'.dat','r')
count = 0
for line in fin:
    count += 1
    if count <= 10: fSolar.write(line)
    if count > 10:
        element = line.split()
        sline = line
        for i in range(1,len(Solar)):
            if element[1] == Solar[i][0]:
                print(element[1])
                sline = line.replace('0.0000D+00',Solar[i][1],1)
        fSolar.write(sline)
```

However when I do run it, the following error comes up:

```
    if element[1] == Solar[i][0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried replacing len(Solar) with 2 to see whether that is the issue, but the same error comes up. 
Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: The code assumes that the length of element is 2  (`element[1]`) - are you sure it is true?

Comment: Which version of Python are you actually asking about?

Comment: I totally agree with @balderman only problem it could have is `element[1]`

Comment: Check your file, make sure all lines have at least 2 columns. Watch out for blank lines. In particular, there may be an empty line at the end.

Comment: @Barmar I think you got it!! When I print element the last row is blank. How do I remove this since I define it using '''element = line.split()'''

Comment: @balderman You are right, my last row is empty. Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Just skip it in the loop. `if not line: continue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have blank lines in the file, which should be skipped.

```
for line in fin:
    count += 1
    if count <= 10: fSolar.write(line)
    if count > 10:
        element = line.split()
        if len(element) < 2:
            continue # skip lines with < 2 columns
        sline = line
        for i in range(1,len(Solar)):
            if element[1] == Solar[i][0]:
                print(element[1])
                sline = line.replace('0.0000D+00',Solar[i][1],1)
        fSolar.write(sline)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to get rid of the error I'm afraid

Comment: Adding ' if not element: continue' in the for loop instead fixed it! Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe the blank line has whitespace on it. I've changed the check for `len(element)`